# MySQL - Update Text as Variation on Original Text

Tags: mysql

I have a column in a table of different domain names that all start with 'www.'.

Is it possible SELECT/UPDATE a variation on an entire column of varchar?

eg original:
www.this.com
www.that.com
www.yes.com

after:
this.com
that.com
yes.com

I've looked at statements like:

```
update table_name set field = replace(field, 'foo', 'bar');
```

However I'm not sure how to modify the original text.

I could write PHP to do this but am interested to know if MySQL alone can do it.

thx
Adam

Comment: I don't understand quite well, but I suppose it would be: update table_name set field = replace(field, 'www.', '');

Comment: thx that worked... appreciated... so obvious now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
UPDATE `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'WWW.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `WHERE` in an `UPDATE` statement.

```
update mytable
set url = substring(url, 5)
where substring(url, 1, 4) = 'www.';
```